# Redis messages contain unicode?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am currently reading in from a Redis server and from the Redis-Cli monitor I am receiving messages that are publishes that have data in-between unicode that looks like this:

\x93\xa6Xz05FH\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xad

Is this generated from some redis related thing or is this because of the original publisher ?

If I publish messages there is no unicode attached so I find it hard to believe this is Redis' doing but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Redis doesn't care about the format of things unless you are using numeric operators such as `incr`, `hincrby`, etc; other than that, strings, hash fields, pub/sub payloads etc are all binary-safe opaque values defined purely by *what the client specified*. Since you mention StackExchange.Redis, if you use a .NET `string` to populate a `RedisValue`, then that `string` will be encoded with UTF-8. However, there are other ways of populating a `RedisValue` for specifying an arbitrary binary payload - the most common of which would be a `byte[]`.

It is possible that redis-cli - since it is a text-based tool - is switching to this representation by a simple heuristic of "does something look non-ASCII / non-printable" - that `\x02` is looking particularly suspicious (is that a `STX`?). But the actual data flowing through redis on a `publish` is raw binary.

Comment: If I print out the RedisValue I get a bunch of the diamonds with the ?s in them. ehich still doesnt help. I really need to know how to mimic this message]

Comment: @Chris sounds like it is arbitrary binary, then; what does the publish code look like? Note that you can convert a RedisValue to a byte[] or similar to consume such data. As examples, in my day job I often broadcast payloads in protobuf serialization format, which doesn't make for convenient text display.

Comment: We dont seem to have a whole lot on the publish code. I could write a parser to receive the data regardless of what it is. What I need to do is be able to replicate these messages and send them myself as well. This is a different project that needs to communicate

Comment: @Chris fair enough, but : redis is simply broadcasting whatever the `publish` sent, which is an opaque binary payload; the redis-cli tool *tries* to display this as ASCII *if it looks like it is ASCII*, but if it clearly isn't ASCII, it will escape pieces of it so that the display remains readable; that doesn't mean that the original payload contained those things - it is just a white lie to make it readable in a text tool. As for what the original payload was: that's up to whatever code called `publish`